# How to find out what codec is being used in a video

Tags: sound, video, codecs

How can i see what codec was used in a video (Audio/Video) and extra information about what to use to reproduce the same compression/quality to the video.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One way of doing this is by using VLC. Open the file in question, right click on it in the playlist and you'll see something like this:

[image: Codec info]

[image: Stats info]

I'm on OS X but the idea is the same.

Another way is to open a terminal, navigate to the directory containing the file and do:

```
file foo.avi
```

This doesn't provide a great deal of information but it is a start.

Comment: OMG. My IQ level just dropped like 99%. I forgot about that. Thanks boehj.

Answer (score 20):

Another command line option with less "harsh" information:

```
ffprobe -show_streams "file.mp4"
```

Even with better output, it's still hard to a regular guy understand. If you need samples of several file formats to test it:

[Video Format Examples](http://www.elecard.com/en/download/videos.html)

Comment: adding `|grep codec` will filter the output

Answer (score 8):

You can get information about *Audio/Video Codecs and additional information* by installing `mediainfo`. Both GUI (Graphical User Interface) and command-line utilities are available. Use these commands to install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mediainfo
```

If you want to install GUI,

```
sudo apt-get install mediainfo-gui
```

for reference visit [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)

Answer (score 5):

The hard to find 'midenitfy' script. An ancient copy looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This is a wrapper around the -identify functionality.
# It is supposed to escape the output properly, so it can be easily
# used in shellscripts by 'eval'ing the output of this script. 
#
# Written by Tobias Diedrich <ranma+mplayer@tdiedrich.de>
# Licensed under GNU GPL.

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Usage: midentify <file> [<file> ...]"
        exit 1
fi

 mplayer -vo null -ao null -frames 0 -identify "$@" 2>/dev/null |
        sed -ne '/^ID_/ {
                           s/[]()|&;<>`'"'"'\\!$" []/\\&/g;p
                        }'
```